# request classified as abuse - Google Youtube API Data

Tags: youtube-data-api

Trying to save a new url and url redirect for OAuth 2 to use G-login for our sites.

Unable to do so and receive error:
Save failed
The request has been classified as abusive and was not allowed to proceed
Tracking number: c7470330412854594

Comment: Hi Google - Does support really monitor this board? I hope to get help as we can't add or edit our urls for Oauth.